# Create function without knowing class name

Tags: java, javabeans

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have this piece of code:

```
    Object selectedCreditId = null;
    int i = 0;
    String selectedCreditName = leasing.getCredit().getDisplayName();
    Collection<DCredRating> selectCreditIds = creditData.getItemIds();
    for (DCredRating id: selectCreditIds) {
        String creditItem = id.getDisplayName();
        if (selectedCreditName.equals(creditItem)) {
            selectedCreditId = creditData.getIdByIndex(i);
        }
            i++;
    }
```

I want to create function using this code.
The function will take `leasing` class and `creditData` BeanItemContainer as parameters and return `selectedCreditId` object.

In other words something like this:

```
private Object getSelectedCreditId(LeasingResP param, BeanItemContainer<...> param2) {
    Object selectedCreditId = null;
    int i = 0;
    LeasingResP leasing = param;
    BeanItemContainer<...> creditData = param2;
    String selectedCreditName = leasing.getCredit().getDisplayName();
    Collection<...> selectCreditIds = creditData.getItemIds();
    for (... id: selectCreditIds) {
        String creditItem = id.getDisplayName();
        if (selectedCreditName.equals(creditItem)) {
            selectedCreditId = creditData.getIdByIndex(i);
        }
            i++;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `creditData` container can be of different class.

Is there any "pretty" way of doing this, or I'll have to write an if block(s) for different classes?

Comment: Does ... have a common interface? Or does DCredRating not inherit any interface?

Comment: It does not inherit any interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really not interested on the type of beans that are collected in the container you could declare the method as following:

```
private Object getSelectedCreditId(LeasingResP param, BeanItemContainer<?> param2) {
    ...
}
```

The "?" means container of *unknown type*, so you only know about your beans that they are of type `Object`.

You could also make the method generic, so that it returns the correct type:

```
private <T extends DCredRating> T getSelectedCreditId(LeasingResP param, BeanItemContainer<? extends T> param2) {
    ...
}
```

A usage for that second variant would be (an example):

```
LeasingResP param = ...
BeanItemContainer<DCredRating> container = ...
DCredRating dcr = getSelectedCreditId(param, container);
```

Comment: I actually need to now beans type (if I understand this correctly), as I create a collection of the same type alter on and iterate through it like this: `for (DCredRating id: selectCreditIds)` where `DCredRating` is the class of the item in the collection

Comment: @konart Simply use the type paremeter: `Collection<T> selectCreditIds = creditData.getItemIds();`. And guess, what you should use in the for-each-loop? :-)

Comment: Ah, I now see that you also must constrain the `T` parameter, as you access the method `getDisplayName()` on that type. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The type paremeter, again? :) <- was answering rhetorical question

Comment: Considering your answer edit: does it mean that I'll have to create two separate functions for two different classes (DCredRating and DAactivityData for example) anyway?

Comment: @konart It depends. Inside the method you are accessing the method `getDisplayName()`. This method does not exist in the type `Object`. So the type parameter `T` only is not enough, as the compiler does not know anything about `T`. You have to restrict that `T` to being a sub type of a type that knows that method. The easiest way is: Let `DCredRating` and `DActivityData` implement an interface (e.g. `DNameDisplayable`) that declares that method. And then restrict the type parameter to `T extends DNameDisplayable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use if statements. You can try this, create `Interface`:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface CreditDataInterface {

    public Collection<Long> getItemIds();

    public String getDisplayName();

    public Object getIdByIndex(int i);
}
```

And implement this interface in `DCredRating` class and others that you want to pass to `getSelectedCreditId` method.
After that you can safety pass `BeanItemContainer<CreditDataInterface>` object to `getSelectedCreditId` method.

Answer (score 0):

"To restrict the *class type* of your `creditData` containers, use a common Interface (that contains only the class signature) for using it as an object type:

```
public interface CreditData {
    //...
}
```

Each kind of `creditData` classes have to implement this new interface.

And now use the Interface as *parent type*:

```
private Object getSelectedCreditId(LeasingResP param, BeanItemContainer<? extends CreditData> param2) {
    //...
    BeanItemContainer<? extends CreditData> creditData = param2;
    //...
    Collection<CreditData> selectCreditIds = creditData.getItemIds();
}
```

==> "`? extends CreditData`" means all objects that extend/are typed as *CreditData*